# No query results for model [App\Card]

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have the following problem:

> No query results for model [App\Card].

My **Route.php**:

```
Route::post('/cards/{card}/notes' , 'NotesController@store');
```

My **NotesController**:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
    return $request->all();
    }
```

And my **View**:

```
@section('content')
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6  col-md-offset-3">
            <h1>  {{  $card->title }}</h1>
            <h4>  {{  $card->created_at }}</h4>

            <ul class="list-group">
                @foreach($card->notes as $note)
                    <li class="list-group-item">{{ $note->body }}</li>
                @endforeach

            </ul>

            <hr>
            <h3>Add a New Note</h3>

            <form action="post" action="/cards/{{ $card->id }}/notes">
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea name="body" class="form-control"></textarea>
            </div>  

            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add note</button>
            </div>  

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
@stop
```

I have two database tables - cards and notes.

Comment: will you make it more clear, show the router?

Comment: show all the router with the /cards/.....

Comment: Are you sure to have a record in your table with the Card ID you are posting?

Comment: What ID are you sending to the route? Does the id really exists?
Show us the request URL

Answer (score 0):

This is my route.php

```
Route::get('/' , 'PagesController@home');
Route::get('/about' , 'PagesController@about');

Route::get('cards' , 'CardsController@index');
Route::get('cards/{card}' , 'CardsController@show');

Route::post('/cards/{card}/notes' , 'NotesController@store');
```

Yes i have records in tables here is pics
cards
[image]
Notes
[image]